# Compare data in two columns and extract the value to another column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column (B) that contains many cities. I want to search in every row of column (A). If it contains a value from column B this value should be written in column (C).

I made a code that searches a static value. I want this value to be the row of (column A).

```
Public Function searchColumn()

V_End_Of_Table = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count 'count the number of rows used'


Dim cell As Range


For Each cell In Range("A1:A" & V_End_Of_Table)
    If InStr(1, cell.Value, "anfa", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        Range("C" & cell.Row).Value = "anfa"
    Else
        Range("C" & cell.Row).Value = "No Match Found"
    End If
Next 'move onto next cell'

End Function
```

**Edit**

```
Column A    |   Column B    |   Column C
------------+---------------+------------ 
casa anfa   |   omar        |   anfa
rabat hassan|   hassan      |   hassan
casa maarouf|   maarouf     |   maarouf
casa omar   |   anfa        |   omar
            |   sultan      |
            |   driss       |
```

Column C is the column that I want to create.

Comment: Just wondering, would a `VLookup` not sort it without any code?

Comment: i think it would solve it if the columns A and b had the same values, but it's not the case. The colum A contains a text that may contain a word in a row of column B

Comment: I was about to ask you to show some sample data and how you want the result. So, we could give a proper solution.

Comment: @PaulFrancis please have a look at my edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 For i = 1 To V_End_Of_Table 'loop for column A
       For j = 1 To V_End_Of_Table 'loop for column B
          If InStr(1, Cells(i, 1).Value, Cells(j, 2).Value) > 0 Then
             Cells(i, 3).Value = Cells(j, 2).Value 'write found B value in c column
             Exit For
          Else
             Cells(i, 3).Value = "no match found"
          End If
          If Cells(j + 1, 2).Value = "" Then
            Exit For
          End If
       Next j
    Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

try this solution

```
Sub test()
Dim oCellSearch As Range, oCellSource As Range, KeySource, Key
Dim Source As Object: Set Source = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim Search As Object: Set Search = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
'Grab the data from the WorkSheets into Dictionaries
n = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
For Each oCellSearch In ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B" & n)
    If oCellSearch.Value <> "" Then
        Search.Add oCellSearch.Row, oCellSearch.Value
    End If
Next
n = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For Each oCellSource In ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" & n)
    If oCellSource.Value <> "" Then
        Source.Add oCellSource.Row, oCellSource.Value
    End If
Next
'Match for contain
For Each Key In Search
    For Each KeySource In Source
        If UCase(Source(KeySource)) Like "*" & UCase(Search(Key)) & "*" Then
            ActiveSheet.Cells(Key, "C").Value = Search(Key): Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with a formula:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH("*"&B1,A:A,0)),"",MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,LEN(A1)))
```